# Sequelize: Invalid value Symbol(col) in include query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Getting this error:

`Error: Invalid value { [Symbol(col)]: 'user.profile_photo' }`

With this Sequelize query:

```
const users = await db.users.findAll({
    where: {
      profile_photo: { [Op.ne]: null },
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.document,
        where: { 
          path: {[Op.not]: [
            { [Op.col]: 'user.profile_photo' }
          ]},
        }
      }
    ],
});
```

I've also tried with `users.profile_photo`.

I'm trying to not include users that have `document.path` which equal `user.profile_photo`. Is there an issue with the query construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
path: {
    [Op.not]: {
        [Op.col]: 'users.profile_photo'
    }
}
```

I know older version of sequelize would allow this:

`path: {[Op.not]: '$users.profile_photo$'}`

I have not tested this but it should be something like that or close.